# Store terminal output in HTML file

Tags: scripting, csv, html

I have a CSV file that I'm counting the occurrences of column 4:

Input:

```
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",Restaurants,1
2,Serveis,11,"Finances i assegurances",Finances i assegurances,1
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",serveis d'allotjament,1
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",Bars   / CIBERCAFE,1
1,Comerç al detall,4,Equipament personal,Calçat i pell,1
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",Bars   / CIBERCAFE,1
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",Bars   / CIBERCAFE,1
1,Comerç al detall,3,Parament de la llar,Mobles i articles fusta i metall,1
2,Serveis,14,"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)",Restaurants,1
```

After using this code:

```
cat file.csv | cut -d, -f 4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

I get the following output:

```
6 "Restaurants
1 Parament de la llar
1 Finances i assegurances
1 Equipament personal
```

And I want to write a script that runs the code and puts this output in an HTML file, in sort of a simple table or like text plain and simple. How would I do that?

Comment: Is that **really** the output you want stored in a table, with `"Restaurants` as one of the fields instead of `"Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)"`?

Answer (score 1):

This script assumes that you will provide the input and output files when it is run.

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

INFILE=$1
OUTFILE=$2

echo "<html><head><title>output from csv</title></head><body><table>" > $OUTFILE

while IFS= read -r line
do
  sed -r 's|\s*([0-9]+)\s+(.+)|<tr><td>\1</td><td>\2</td></tr>|' >> $OUTFILE
done < <(cat $INFILE | cut -d, -f 4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr)

echo "</table></body></html>" >> $OUTFILE
```

Essentially you just build a very basic HTML scaffold, and loop through the inputs. I used `sed` to parse and transform the inputs, but there are numerous ways this can be done.

```
usage: bash ./script.sh infile outfile
```

Comment: Do I run it like this: `./file.sh input.csv > output.html` ?

Comment: @LlemColop no; if you `chmod a+x file.sh` you can then `./file.sh input.csv output.html`. The script doesn't expect redirection (nothing is written to _STDOUT_).

Comment: OP said, "...a script that runs the code and puts this output in an HTML file..." so that was what I was trying very specifically to achieve. Personally I think STDOUT redirection is a better way to go for this, but that is just my preference.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to process a CSV file (with quotes and commas inside fields) as if it's a simple comma-delimited file.  This won't work.  You need to use a CSV parser that understands quoted fields.

For example, to count column four using `perl` and its [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module, with an output format similar to that of `uniq -c`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift;  # use first arg as the input filename
my %column;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1});
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "couldn't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  # perl arrays start from zero, so row[3] is the fourth field.
  $column{$$row[3]}++;
}
close $fh;

# reverse sort the %column hash by value
foreach my $key (sort { $column{$b} <=> $column{$a} } keys %column) {
  printf "%7i\t%s\n", $column{$key}, $key;
};
```

If the input file contains any utf-8 characters, change the `'<'` in the `open()` statement on line 10 to `'<:encoding(utf8)'`

Output:

```
$ ./count.pl file.csv 
      6 Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)
      1 Equipament personal
      1 Finances i assegurances
      1 Parament de la llar
```

The script below uses the same Text::CSV module to produce a bare minimum HTML table, printed to stdout.

This script also uses [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) from the [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Parser) module collection to ensure that nothing in the input columns can break the HTML (e.g. `<` and `>` characters need to be encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` to prevent them from being interpreted by a browser)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use HTML::Entities;

my $file = shift;  # use first arg as the input filename

print "<html>\n<body>\n";
print "<table>\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1});
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die "couldn't open $file: $!";

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
  print '<tr>';
  foreach my $i (@{ $row }) {
    print "<td>" . encode_entities($i) . "</td>"
  };
  print "</tr>\n";
}
close $fh;

print "</table>\n";
print "</body>\n</html>\n";
```

Output:

```
$ ./table.pl file.csv 
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>Restaurants</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>11</td><td>Finances i assegurances</td><td>Finances i assegurances</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>serveis d&#39;allotjament</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>Bars   / CIBERCAFE</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Comer&ccedil; al detall</td><td>4</td><td>Equipament personal</td><td>Cal&ccedil;at i pell</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>Bars   / CIBERCAFE</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>Bars   / CIBERCAFE</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Comer&ccedil; al detall</td><td>3</td><td>Parament de la llar</td><td>Mobles i articles fusta i metall</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Serveis</td><td>14</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td><td>Restaurants</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This can easily be adapted to produce a markdown pipe table or a TeX table, or whatever other kind of table is required.

Note: all of the library modules mentioned are available packaged for most linux distributions.  On Debian and related distros, for example, they can be installed with `sudo apt install libtext-csv-perl libhtml-parser-perl`.  Otherwise, they can be installed with `cpan`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the non-HTML output I think you really want using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^([^,]*,){3}"?|"?(,[^,]*){2}$/,"")
    cnts[$0]++
}
END {
    for (type in cnts) {
        print cnts[type], type
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
6 Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)
1 Finances i assegurances
1 Parament de la llar
1 Equipament personal
```

Pipe that to `sort` or use GNU awk for `sorted_in` if you care about the order. To get the output as an HTML table would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^([^,]*,){3}"?|"?(,[^,]*){2}$/,"")
    cnts[$0]++
}
END {
    print "<html>\n<table>"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (type in cnts) {
        printf "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", cnts[type], type
    }
    print "</table>\n</html>"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>6</td><td>Restaurants, bars i hotels (Inclos hostals, pensions i fondes)</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Finances i assegurances</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Parament de la llar</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Equipament personal</td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

and in that case you could still sort with `sort` by isolating the first and last 2 lines before sorting but using GNU awk for `sorted_in` is simpler so I included that in the script this time.

If you're concerned about undesirable characters (`&`, `<`, or `>`) appearing in the input and breaking your HTML output then just add this right above the `cnts[$0]++` line:

```
gsub(/&/,"\\&amp;"); gsub(/</,"\\&lt;"); gsub(/>/,"\\&gt;")
```